# Indirect modification of overloaded property App\\Models\\product::$variations has no effect

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

```
$product_model = product::findOrFail($product['product_id']);

$product_model->variations['variations'][$product['variation_index']]['quantity'] += 1;

$product_model->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `cast` a field to `array`, you must store it in a new variable like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

```php
$product_model = product::findOrFail($product['product_id']);

$variations = $product_model->variations;

$variations['variations'][$product['variation_index']]['quantity'] += 1;

$product_model->variations = $variations;

$product_model->save();
```

Or you can do [what you want](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-object-and-collection-casting) if you have laravel 9